# Remember my sort order on SO Search

Tags: feature-request, search, user-experience

Whenever one initiates a new search the sort order reverts to "Relevance."

If I change the sort order to "Newest" and make a new search, again the sort order reverts to "Relevance."

I would like the sort order that I choose to stick.

Answer (score 7):

For those who have installed my [Advanced Search Helper, Saved Search (Bookmarks), and Navigation Improvements](https://stackapps.com/q/7971) userscript, the last sort order will now be saved.

[View commit diff](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/commit/f2be8cfc8851c8d8a5ab66320ba2c72502216f69)

[image]

*P.S.: with this userscript, you can even change the sort order before submitting the search form. For more info on what this script can do for you, check out https://stackapps.com/q/7971*

Comment: \*sadface\* You mean I didn't invent the wheel?

Answer (score 6):

I totally agree with this feature request. While we're waiting for it to be officially implemented, you can use [this userscript](https://gist.github.com/patrickroberts/b6937c0ffd9b1e8cea618f43370eea60) I threw together when I saw your question. It will automatically prompt your browser for installation if you click the "Raw" button on the gist and you have tampermonkey or greasemonkey. It requires a modern browser, but I'm sure that's not a problem for most people who frequent this site ;)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Overflow Sticky Search Filter
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.0.0
// @description  Use localStorage to remember most recently used search filter
// @author       Patrick Roberts
// @match        https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const tabsFilter = document.querySelector('.tabs-filter');

    if (tabsFilter !== null) {
        tabsFilter.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
            if (target.matches('a[href]')) {
                localStorage.tabsFilter = new URLSearchParams(target.search).get('tab');
            }
        });
    }

    if ('tabsFilter' in localStorage) {
        for (const form of document.querySelectorAll('form[action="/search"]')) {
            const tab = document.createElement('input');

            tab.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            tab.setAttribute('name', 'tab');
            tab.setAttribute('value', localStorage.tabsFilter);

            form.prepend(tab);
        }
    }
})();
```